# Uniformity on a closed unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence of functions, which are all analytical on the open unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1\}$ and continuous on the closed unit disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \leq 1\}$. Suppose that $f$ has the same characteristics and that $f_n \to f$ is uniform on the unit circle $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$. Proof that $f_n\to f$ is uniform on the closed unit disk.

---

What I've tried so far:

I know that uniformity demands that $\forall \epsilon > 0\  \exists N \in\mathbb{N}_{>0} : \forall n > N: |f_n(x)-f(x)|< \epsilon$. Since the $f_n$

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Neal Your comment seems to claim that, if a sequence of continuous functions on a compact space converges pointwise to a continuous function, then the convergence is uniform. But that's not true.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Well that's embarrassing. Yes indeed, my comment was false. I'll just blame it on not enough coffee this morning.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Maximum modulus principle.